# How do I start mysqld with options

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, mysqld-safe

I need to start up `mysqld` with command line options as from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables

I normally do `sudo service mysqld start`, but passing the option as `sudo service mysqld start --skip-grant-tables` does not seem to work.

Alternatively I have tried starting as a daemon,

`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

But it seems to terminate too soon:

> 131101 04:59:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/vagrant.example.com.err'.
>
> 131101 04:59:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
>
> 131101 05:00:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/vagrant.example.com.pid ended

My last option seems to specify the option in `/etc/my.cnf` instead, but is there any way to do it via the command line?

Comment: which version of centos are you using?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 6.4

Comment: I think the file is located here: /etc/init.d/mysqld edit this to have the commandline parameters you want then do the "sudo service mysqld start"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command seems fine.

You should check /var/lib/mysql/vagrant.example.com.err log file to see why it's failing.

Comment: It turns out that the error was entirely due to something I failed to mention - `131101 4:59:58 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--skipnetworking'`, but the error log helped me catch that, so I'm accepting this as the answer.